# Twitter API wrapper

Tags: python

I'm working on a project where I need to get all followers from a specific user and store this info in a database. I have done this and so far it suits my needs, but I'd like to make it more "professional" and would love to hear your suggestions.

The first code is **twitter.py** and the 2nd one is **app.py**

```
import requests

class TwitterAPI():

    def __init__(self):
        with open('token.ini') as ini:
            self.token = ini.readline()

    def get_follower(self, action, **kwargs):
        params = kwargs.keys()

        if 'user_id' not in params and 'screen_name' not in params:
            raise TypeError('Incorrect parameters, expecting `user_id` or `screen_name`')

        url = {
            'list': 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/ids.json',
            'info': 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json'
        }

        r = requests.get(
            url[action],
            params = kwargs,
            headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + self.token},
        )

        return r.json() if r.status_code == 200 else r.status_code
```

---

```
import twitter
import sqlite3
from datetime import datetime

conn = sqlite3.connect('twitter_analytics.sqlite3')
c = conn.cursor()

api = twitter.TwitterAPI()
followers = api.get_follower(action='list', screen_name='Croves')

c.execute("INSERT INTO user(twitter_screen_name, created_at) VALUES(?, ?)", ('Croves', datetime.now()))
conn.commit()

user_id = c.lastrowid

for count, follower in enumerate(followers['ids']):
    info = api.get_follower(action='info', user_id=follower)
    c.execute("""
        INSERT INTO user_followers(user_id, id_str, name, screen_name, location, url, description, protected, verified, followers_count, friends_count, profile_banner_url, profile_image_url_https, created_at)
        VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    """, (
        user_id,
        info.get('id_str'),
        info.get('name'),
        info.get('screen_name'),
        info.get('location'),
        info.get('url'),
        info.get('description'),
        info.get('protected'),
        info.get('verified'),
        info.get('followers_count'),
        info.get('friends_count'),
        info.get('profile_banner_url'),
        info.get('profile_image_url_https'),
        datetime.now()
    ))

    if count % 10 == 0:
        conn.commit()

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

A few suggestions:

### PEP-8

Some selected excerpts [from pep-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

- Avoid extraneous whitespace immediately inside parentheses, brackets or braces:
- Don't use spaces around the = sign when used to indicate a keyword argument, or when used to indicate a default value for an unannotated function parameter
- Surround top-level function and class definitions with two blank lines.
- Use blank lines in functions, sparingly, to indicate logical sections.
- Imports should be grouped in the following order:

  - Standard library imports.
  - Related third party imports.
  - Local application/library specific imports.

  You should put a blank line between each group of imports.

### Token

Reading the token in the constructor of your API wrapper is a very bad behaviour. Your constructor should instead be initialised with the same, and the caller needs to provide proper tokens.

### Functions

You currently have a single function doing 2 different tasks/actions. Instead, split it to do one thing each.

### Return values/error handling

The return type of your API wrapper is inconsistent. In case of error, it just returns an integer value, whereas in the caller (`app.py`) you are always assuming that the result will never be an integer (no errors ever?).

Raise an exception in the wrapper itself if the API fails, or the caller should have conditional check to validate the same.

### sqlite3 bulk operation

The sqlite3 package has a method `executemany` to perform bulk insert in a single pass. Check the docs for [the same here](https://devdocs.io/python%7E3.8/library/sqlite3#sqlite3.Cursor.executemany).

### `if __name__` block

Put execution logic of your script inside the `if __name__ == "__main__"` block. A more descriptive explanation can be checked [on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/419185/1190388).

---

### Example rewrite

#### `twitter.py`

```
import requests


class TwitterAPI:
    API_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1"

    def __init__(self, api_token: str):
        self.token = api_token
        self.headers = {
            "Authorization": f"Bearer {self.token}"
        }

    def _request(self, url, **params) -> dict:
        response = requests.get(
            url,
            params=params,
            headers=self.headers,
        )
        if not response.ok:
            raise Exception("API returned invalid response.")
        return response.json()

    def get_user_info(self, user_id: str) -> dict:
        return self._request(
            f"{self.API_URL}/users/show.json",
            user_id=user_id
        )

    def get_followers(self, screen_name: str) -> dict:
        return self._request(
            f"{self.API_URL}/followers/ids.json",
            screen_name=screen_name,
        )
```

`app.py`

```
from datetime import datetime
import sqlite3

import twitter

SQLITE_DB = "twitter_analytics.sqlite3"
TWITTER_SCREEN_NAME = "Croves"


def initialise_sqlite(db_name: str):
    connection = sqlite3.connect(db_name)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    return connection, cursor


def get_api_token() -> str:
    with open('token.ini') as ini:
        return ini.readline()


def get_followers_info(api: twitter.TwitterAPI, follower_ids: list):
    for user_id in follower_ids:
        user_info = api.get_user_info(user_id=user_id)
        yield [
            user_info.get('id_str'),
            user_info.get('name'),
            user_info.get('screen_name'),
            user_info.get('location'),
            user_info.get('url'),
            user_info.get('description'),
            user_info.get('protected'),
            user_info.get('verified'),
            user_info.get('followers_count'),
            user_info.get('friends_count'),
            user_info.get('profile_banner_url'),
            user_info.get('profile_image_url_https'),
        ]


def main():
    token = get_api_token()
    connection, cursor = initialise_sqlite(SQLITE_DB)
    api = twitter.TwitterAPI(token)
    followers = api.get_followers(screen_name=TWITTER_SCREEN_NAME)
    cursor.execute(
        "INSERT INTO user(twitter_screen_name, created_at) VALUES (?, ?)",
        (TWITTER_SCREEN_NAME, datetime.now())
    )
    connection.commit()
    user_id = cursor.lastrowid
    user_followers_info = [
        (user_id, *follower_info, datetime.now())
        for follower_info in get_followers_info(api, followers["ids"])
    ]
    cursor.executemany(
        """
            INSERT INTO
            user_followers(
                user_id, id_str, name, screen_name, location, url,
                description, protected, verified, followers_count,
                friends_count, profile_banner_url, profile_image_url_https,
                created_at
            )
            VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
        """,
        user_followers_info,
    )
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

### Note

The above is an example rewrite. You can (and should) modify

- aggregating the followers' information
- a wrapper for interaction with sqlite3 etc.
- threading call for gathering information about followers in parallel

etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. Your syntax is very different from mine `def get_user_info(self, user_id: str) -> dict:` what the arrow dict and the str mean? How can I learn this?

Comment: @Croves That's type hinting: https://devdocs.io/python~3.8/library/typing